# Fuzzy Extractor constructor for sequence reconciliation

Tags: cryptanalysis, randomness, information-theory

The famous works on Fuzzy Extraction considers $set$ of inputs. I am interested in reconciliation for sequence of close data. Here order of elements are important unlike in previous one. Are there constructions focusing on sequence rather set reconciliation?

Comment: value/position could be encoded into a sequence characteristic polynomial just like values only were encoded into set characteristic polnomial. Self-reference: IACR preprint 2008/357

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hamming distance based reconciliation for close secrets as maintained in famous paper by Dodis et.al on Fuzzy Extraction for close/noisy bio-metric data